# Set up git central folder and user repository on same machine

Tags: git

I'm new to git and trying to learn by using it.

I want to set up a folder to be the central repository and another folder to be the a users repository all both on the same machine.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use GitHub or BitBucket?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your central repository lives at `/path/to/central/repo`, you can `git clone` the central repository to create a copy at `/path/to/user/repo`.

```
git clone /path/to/central/repo /path/to/user/repo
```

This command clones the central git repository to `/path/to/user/repo` and configures the central git repository as a [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) named "origin" for the user repository (which you can `git push` to and `git pull` from). You can verify the configuration with `git remote -v`

```
origin  /path/to/central/repo (fetch)
origin  /path/to/central/repo (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

It possible of course.

#### How?

1. clone the folder to a different pace
2. use `git workdir`

#### git worktree: one Git repository with multiple working trees

> It's not very difficult to switch a single Git repository between multiple branches, or to create a second local clone of a repository.
>
> This lets you work on two branches simultaneously, or start long-running tests in one clone while continuing development in the other. However, maintaining multiple clones of a repository means extra work to keep the clones in sync with each other and with any remote repositories.
>
> The new Git subcommand git worktree creates additional working trees connected to an existing Git repository [1].
>
> Each linked working tree is a pseudo-repository with its own checked-out working copy. Its .git is actually a file that refers to the history and references from the main repository.
>
> Suppose you're working in a Git repository on a branch called feature, when a user reports a high-urgency bug in master.
>
> First you create a linked working tree with a new branch, hotfix, checked out relative to master, and switch to that directory:

```
$ git worktree add -b hotfix ../hotfix origin/master
Enter ../hotfix (identifier hotfix)
Branch hotfix set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'hotfix'
$ cd ../hotfix
```